# Black points in scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot, figure

This is likely an elementary question, but I can't figure out how to plot black points in a scatter plot!

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(255)
y = range(255)
color = range(255)
plt.scatter(x, y, c=color)
```

This does not result in black dots!

Answer (score 7):

Not sure if this is what you want, but why not simply specify the color to be black?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = range(255)
y = range(255)
# color = range(255)  not needed?
plt.scatter(x, y, c='black')
```

Edit: To make things a little more clear maybe:
You can specify colors in pyplot in different ways:

- use built-in colors accessible via strings (e.g. `color="blue"` or `c="b"`)
- use greyshades via floats in the range of 0-1 (e.g. `color=0.75`)
- use hex-strings (e.g. `color='#eeefff'`)
- use rgb-tuples, each in the range of 0-1 (e.g. `color=(0.5, 0.5, 0.5)`)